# meaning of shlok सुवृत्तामसुवृत्तां वाप्पहं त्वामद्य मैथिलि

Tags: mahabharata, rama, sita

There is a debate going on about the shock

> सुवृत्तामसुवृत्तां वाप्पहं त्वामद्य मैथिलि| नोत्सहे परिभोगाय श्वावलीढं
> हविर्यथा ॥

As explained by the teacher of IAS coaching Drishti in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6E-_CZf85mA&t=597s) is correct or not?
How authentic is this as well?

Comment: Check out Nityānanda Miśra's take on this on his YouTube channel(2-3 videos) where he beautifully explains the true meaning of these so called controversial verses from Mahabharata.

Comment: Rishi Valmiki is the dhrashta of Ramayana, whose compostion is based on the exact happening of scenarios , visible to Him. As this verse has not occurred in Valmiki Ramayana, it cannot taken at its face value. As for other Ramayanas  by several other great  Kavis are concerned, they might have used  literary devices taking privilege over their poetic license..If the intention of the speaker is only to bring up  discord and turmoil, only linguistic/pauranic expert can respond to it aptly. @Rāmachandra, thanks for info. Please post the links also

Comment: @Athrey Ji very nicely put ! (Sorry I actually forgot posting the links earlier :(  )

Video 1: https://youtu.be/7a2V3mzGlcQ

Video 2:https://youtu.be/xzfCSscgcHM

(Note:video is in hindi)